# Sqlite query - Where In (subquery)

Tags: sqlite, subquery

**Goal:**
I'm working on a windows phone app that allows you to save birthdays. But windows phone doesn't allow you to save more than 50 reminders, so what I'm trying to do is:

I want to get a list of the next 50 birthdays-DAYS. But this list has to be distinct, because if for example the next 50 birthdays all fall on the same day, I don't want to create 50 reminders for 1 day, I just want to create 1 reminder for all those 50 birthdays.

This part of the query will create the next birthday (if the birthday is already passed, it will create a birthday for next year)

```
CASE WHEN strftime('%m-%d', Bday) < strftime('%m-%d', 'now')
THEN strftime('2015-%m-%d', Bday)
ELSE strftime('2014-%m-%d', Bday)
END AS Bday
```

So this is my full query, which doesn't work ...:

```
SELECT id, type, details, 
                CASE WHEN strftime('%m-%d', Bday) < strftime('%m-%d', 'now')
                THEN strftime('2015-%m-%d', Bday)
                ELSE strftime('2014-%m-%d', Bday)
                END AS Bday
FROM Birthday 
WHERE Bday IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT 
         CASE WHEN strftime('%m-%d', Bday) < strftime('%m-%d', 'now')
         THEN strftime('2015-%m-%d', Bday)
         ELSE strftime('2014-%m-%d', Bday)
         END AS nextBday
       FROM Birthday
       ORDER BY nextBday
       LIMIT 50)
ORDER BY Bday
```

If I run the subquery seperatly, it give me the results I'm looking for:

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
```

If I run the main query without the where i get:

```
id  type       details            Bday
1   11111      admin@sqlfiddle.com    2015-01-01
3   33333      admin@sqlfiddle.com    2015-01-01
2   22222      @sqlfiddle             2015-01-02
4   44444      @sqlfiddle             2015-01-02
```

But combined, I get no results ...

I made this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/58849/6/0

I hope some1 can help me with this!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying rename a field in your `AS` clause.  The `BDay` field in your `WHERE` clause refers to the `bday` in your table definition, not the one in your `SELECT` clause.

To fix your issue, change to this instead (gives two rows of results on your fiddle):

```
SELECT id, type, details, 
 CASE WHEN strftime('%m-%d', Bday) < strftime('%m-%d', 'now')
 THEN strftime('2015-%m-%d', Bday)
 ELSE strftime('2014-%m-%d', Bday)
 END AS FBDay
FROM Birthday 
WHERE FBDay IN
 (SELECT DISTINCT 
     CASE WHEN strftime('%m-%d', Bday) < strftime('%m-%d', 'now')
     THEN strftime('2015-%m-%d', Bday)
     ELSE strftime('2014-%m-%d', Bday)
     END AS nextBday
  FROM Birthday
  ORDER BY nextBday
  LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY Bday
```

Comment: Going to check this tomorrow, but thanks in advance!